# Catch net use exception in powershell

Tags: powershell, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I am having difficulty to catch a net use exception in powershell.

```
foreach ($k in $file){

        try{
            net use \\$k\share $password /USER:$username > null 
            Copy-Item D:\setup.exe \\$k\share 
            net use \\$k\share /delete > null 
            write-host "Copied file to \\$k\share"

        }
        catch [System.Exception]{
            continue
        }

}
```

If the script cannot authenticate to the machine, I want the script to silently continue, but instead I get the following error

```
net : System error 1326 has occurred.
At D:\Script\log_into.ps1:25 char:17
+                 net use \\$k\share $password /USER:$username > null
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 1326 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

The user name or password is incorrect.
net : The network connection could not be found.
At D:\Script\log_into.ps1:27 char:17
+                 net use \\$k\share /delete > null
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The network con...d not be found.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: You're getting this error because `net use` doesn't throw exceptions that any .NET code can capture.

Comment: have you tried to use the `net use` option `/persistent:no` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the drive using PowerShell cmdlets instead so that you can capture any exceptions properly.

This will only work with PowerShell 3.0 and newer, as there's a bug with the `-Credential` parameter in older versions (it just doesn't work). If you need v2 compatibility, post a comment & I'll update.

```
$userPass = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $userPass

foreach ($k in $file){

        try{
            New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\$k\share -Credential $Credential;
            Copy-Item D:\setup.exe Z:\
            Remove-PSDrive -name Z
            write-host "Copied file to \\$k\share"

        }
        catch [System.Exception]{
            continue
        }

}
```

Comment: when I execute get-host it returns Version: 4.0

Comment: I tried the code and it prints out the error instead of continuing silently - it prints the error "New-PSDrive : Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous 
connections to the server or shared resource and try again"

Comment: I added -ErrorAction Stop to New-PSDrive, now it works

Comment: If the drive mapping already exists with the same credentials, why are you attempting to re-create it in your script?

Answer (score 2):

Try referencing the $LASTEXITCODE value.

So something like this could work.

```
    Try
    {
        # Set the credentials for the destination server
        Write-Output "net use starting"
        net use \\$k\share $password /USER:$username > null
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
            write-host "net use successful"
        } else {
            write-error "Error non zero net use exit code."
            throw $error[0].Exception
        }
    }
    Catch
    {
        write-error "Error setting the remote server credentials.Halting the script."
        throw $error[0].Exception
    }
```

This solution was built from reading these queries :

[How to obtain exit code when I invoke NET USE command via Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475361/how-to-obtain-exit-code-when-i-invoke-net-use-command-via-powershell)

[handling net use error messages with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272345/handling-net-use-error-messages-with-powershell)

Answer (score -2):

I know this is old, but your drive letters are backwards.  it's k$ not $k...

Comment: Incorrect : $k is a variable in this case and not a hidden share.