# How to capture all output from icacls.exe in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, error-handling, icacls

We have a script that runs once a week and adjusts all permissions on a specific file share. I mainly use a PowerShell script for this but also execute icacls.exe in some parts. As there are lots of files, errors will occur when running icacls.exe

At the start of my script, I reset all permissions on each customer folder and after that on all its childitems. One part of this consists of resetting the object owner.

I'm calling icacls.exe like this.

```
$ICACLSResult = icacls "$OBJPath\*" /setowner $OBJOwner /t /c /q | Out-String
```

I then check the string `$ICACLSResult` for a specific text to check whether errors occured or not and also append the string itself to my error message.

```
if($ICACLSResult -notmatch "bei 0 Dateien ist ein Verarbeitungsfehler aufgetreten" -and $ICACLSResult -notmatch "Failed processing 0 files")
{
    Add-Error -SED ($ErrorMSG + $ICACLSResult) -Level 2 -AddErrorInfo $False -ExitScript $False

    Throw("AnErrorOccured")
}
```

However, the actual content of the variable `$ICACLSResult` looks like this.

```
Successfully processed 13970 files; Failed processing 5 files
```

But when I run the same command directly within the console, it looks like this.

```
PS C:\Users\User> $ICACLSResult = icacls "$OBJPath\*" /setowner $OBJOwner /t /c /q | Out-String

D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File.txt: The system cannot find the path specified.
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File.txt: The system cannot find the path specified.
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File.txt: The system cannot find the path specified.
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File.txt: The system cannot find the path specified.
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File.txt: The system cannot find the path specified.

PS C:\Users\User>
```

But again `$ICACLSResult` looks like this.

```
PS C:\Users\User> $ICACLSResult
Successfully processed 13970 files; Failed processing 5 files

PS C:\Users\User>
```

Without these detailed error messages, there's no use logging the variable `$ICACLSResult` since all it says is how many files failed but not which files specifically.

How can I get this additional info as well and store it in `$ICACLSResult`? All I want are the paths of the failed files.

**What I've also tried so far**

1. `$ICACLSResult = icacls "$OBJPath\*" /setowner $OBJOwner /t /c /q 2>&1`
2. `$ICACLSResult = icacls "$OBJPath\*" /setowner $OBJOwner /t /c /q 2>&1 | Out-String -Stream -Width 9999`
3. `$ICACLSResult = icacls "$OBJPath\*" /setowner $OBJOwner /t /c /q`

**Why they don't work**

1. Too much information, contains linebreaks
2. Too much information, contains linebreaks
3. Desired information still not in variable `$ICACLSResult`

Comment: you should redirect stderr and eventually stdout to grab all output, here´s an example from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272345/handling-net-use-error-messages-with-powershell/39294208#39294208

Comment: For issue #3 simply run `cmd /c "2>&1" icacls .....................`

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, that works great. if you post this as an answer, i can accept it if you like.

Comment: I wasn't sure this could answer your question entirely. Is it so?

Comment: yeah, it's exactly what i needed. the desired output is now in my variable and even as an array object which is even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method of keeping errors in the output is using the `cmd` Windows command line utility to redirect STDERR into STDOUT. Use quotes around the redirection operator to pass it to cmd:

```
$log = cmd /c "2>&1" someutilityname /some /parameters
```

For example:

```
$log = cmd /c "2>&1" icacls "$OBJPath\*" /setowner $OBJOwner /t /c /q
```

Now the $log variable is an array of output strings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as another way, you can obtain the same 
Get-Acl 
Set-Acl